# Ninject equivalent to MEF AssemblyCatalog

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, mef

In MEF, an `AssemblyCatalog` is used to scan an assembly for all exported types and configure the container. Is there an equivalent with Ninject?

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ninject, the ability to use attributes on types and scan assemblies to add bindings is provided by an extension named [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.conventions/3.2.0).

1. **Add the conventions package**, e.g. using the Package Manager Console:

   ```
   Install-Package Ninject.Extensions.Conventions
   ```
2. **Create some custom attribute** to use on your services. This will be the equivalent to the `ExportAttribute` in MEF:

   ```
   public enum ExportScope
   {
       Singleton,
       Transient
   }

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class ExportAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public ExportAttribute(Type serviceInterface, ExportScope scope = ExportScope.Singleton)
       {
           this.ServiceInterface = serviceInterface;
           this.Scope = scope;
       }

       public Type ServiceInterface { get; set; }

       public ExportScope Scope { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. **Create a custom BindingGenerator** that uses our `ExportAttribute` to bind a type to the given interface:

   ```
   public class ExportAttributeBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
   {
       public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
       {
           var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<ExportAttribute>();
           var serviceType = attribute.ServiceInterface;

           if (!serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
           {
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Error in ExportAttribute: Cannot bind type '{0}' to type '{1}'.", 
                   serviceType, type));
           }

           var binding = bindingRoot.Bind(serviceType).To(type);

           switch (attribute.Scope)
           {
               case ExportScope.Singleton:
                   yield return (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>) binding.InSingletonScope();
                   break;
               case ExportScope.Transient:
                   yield return (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>) binding.InTransientScope();
                   break;
               default:
                   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Create an extension method** to use on the kernel and add the convention:

   ```
   public static class NinjectBindingExtensions
   {
       public static void BindExportsInAssembly(this IBindingRoot root, Assembly assembly)
       {
           root.Bind(c => c.From(assembly)
                             .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
                             .SelectAllClasses()
                             .WithAttribute<ExportAttribute>()
                             .BindWith<ExportAttributeBindingGenerator>());
       }
   }
   ```

Now this seems like a lot of work for something so common, but it's very flexible and extensible. It does whatever you want it to do. Put it in a utilities class library and use it wherever you want like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{

}

[Export(typeof(IBar), ExportScope.Transient)]
public class Bar : IBar
{

}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestNinjectConventions()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.BindExportsInAssembly(typeof(IFoo).Assembly);

        kernel.Get<IFoo>().Should().Be(kernel.Get<IFoo>());
        kernel.Get<IBar>().Should().NotBe(kernel.Get<IBar>());
    }
}
```